# Does optional parameter and optional attribute not supported together?

Tags: c#, .net, optional-parameters

```
public void ObjTest(StringBuilder sb, List<string> list, int i = 0,  [Optional] string bs)
{
    ......
 }
```

The above code throwing compilation error " Optional parameters must appear after all required parameters ". Does optional parameter and optional attribute not supported together in same method parameter, but it allows params arry after optional paramer ?

Comment: I don't understand your question (or why you've repeated it verbatim in the title and the body, using a heading in the body). Are you asking *why* something is allowed/forbidden, or what *is* allowed? Please clarify.

Comment: C# never formally supported the [Optional] attribute.  Its meaning was changed in version 4, used to make [COM interop easier](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24695592/17034).  This is not something you ought to consider using in your own code, given the oddball default values it can generate.

Comment: @ Hans Passant- Thanks for the information related to COM interop details. However I am able to use its like a optional parameter at framework 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use them in conjunction but the optional parameter (the language construct) must be the last parameter in the parameter list.

```
public void X(StringBuilder sb, List<string> list, [Optional] string bs, int i = 0)
{
}
```