# Optional parameters must appear after all required parameters

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got this error when update my project and run the Api Updater of unity3d:

> Optional parameters must appear after all required parameters

Any idea what's wrong with this code?

```
public static Transform AddChild(this Transform tfm, string name = "", 
    [Optional] Vector3 offset)
```

Comment: Got **what** error?

Comment: The error is referring to `string name = ""` being an optional parameter. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171095/use-optional-defaultparametervalue-attribute-or-not).

Comment: Where did you get the idea to use [Optional] in C#?

Comment: :facepalm: * I see what you did now.  The error text is the title of the question. And "this error" refers to the title.  That's a little unusual for Stack Overflow, I think.  Better to post the error text into the body of your question.  It's a tiny bit confusing.

Comment: Similar question: [Does optional parameter and optional attribute not supported together?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25095627/150605).  @JonathonChase The [`OptionalAttribute` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.optionalattribute) is for [COM interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/interop/applying-interop-attributes).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last parameter being optional give it a default value as well

```
public static Transform AddChild(this Transform tfm, string name = "", Vector3 offset = default)
```

see [c# - Optional Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments) for more information.

Comment: The docs list `Vector3.zero` as a static property, not a constant. If that's correct then I don't think C# will let you use it as an optional default. `default(Vector3)` or just the shorthand `default` should mean the same thing, though.

Comment: yes right it has to be `default` or `new Vector3()`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want `offset` to be an optional parameter. To do this, you'll need to decide what an appropriate default value would be if someone doesn't provide it in their method call. If you've got logic that treats no offset as a special case, I'd suggest making it nullable.

```
public static Transform AddChild(this Transform tfm, string name = "", Vector3? offset = null)
```

If not providing an offset means that the offset is zero (putting this transform in the same place as its parent), then set it to `default`.

```
public static Transform AddChild(this Transform tfm, string name = "", Vector3 offset = default)
```

Comment: There's a difference between `Vector3` and `Vector3?`. The question mark is C# shorthand for `Nullable<Vector3>`.

Comment: ooooh ok now I got it .. nevermind then ;)